# Different 'time's called in similar environments in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, time

I was told that people using bash will have to differentiate between the shell-builtin `time` and `/usr/bin/time` ( `time(1)` ). I had to time a program and also had to find ways to automate input, using `echo` and string redirection `<<<`. These are the results,

```
$ time python3 -c "a=input("");print(a)" <<< "12"
12

real    0m0.023s
user    0m0.020s
sys 0m0.000s
```

The shell-built-in is called in this ^ case.

```
$ echo "12" | time python3 -c "a=input("");print(a)"
12
0.01user 0.00system 0:00.02elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 6524maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+593minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

`time(1)` is being called in this case.

Why is this happening ? Are they different environments ?

Using Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64

Comment: Your second example did not use /usr/bin/time but intrinsic code from the shell. The format in use is typically controlled via the shell variable TIMEFORMAT and as your output contains more than just the times, I woould guess that you use csh, zsh or a recent Bourne Shell.

Comment: @schily: No, it used external time in second case. Try `echo | time` and `/usr/bin/time` to see the same output. It's sound like a bug, `echo | time` work well in `zsh`, `ksh`. Also `echo |<literal newline>time` yield error in `bash`.

Comment: No, as you mentioned that you use zsh, "time" refers to the reserved word "time" in zsh. If you like to call /usr/bin/time, call /usr/bin/time.

Comment: @schily: What do you mean? You said that `our second example did not use /usr/bin/time but intrinsic code from the shell`, I gave the example to demonstrated that `echo | time` in `bash` use the external `time` instead of reserved word `time`.

Comment: You used a shell intrinsic, call `type time`to understand your mistake. If you like to use the external command, you cannot just type time but need to use `/usr/bin/time`

Comment: @schily: I know it, that's also my expected behavior from reading man `bash`, `echo | time` should use reserved word `time` instead of external `time`. That's why I said it's sound like a bug.

Comment: So what platform are you on that /usr/bin/time gives such a strange output?

Comment: @schily: I'm on Debian 8 Jessie, with `bash 4.3.33`. I bet that's the `bash` parsing issue. You can run `set -x`, then see how `bash` parsed in two cases of OP's question. Also note that external `time` will use the format in following order: from command line, from `TIME` environment variable, default format. The output in question is the same as what manpage said.

Comment: Well, /usr/bin/time typically referts to a halfway POSIX compliant implementation and your output does not look POSIX compliant at all. I currently have no bash4 and Linux available and am in a _really_ slow line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two types of `time` commands. One is shell built-in, belongs to bash. That's the one you see in your first example. Second one , is `/usr/bin/time`, that's the second one you saw.  As for why it's different output, it's because you cannot pipe output to shell builtins. 
[More on that here](https://askubuntu.com/a/404147/295286)

Answer (score 5):

The [structure of a pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines) doesn't allow time in the middle, only at the start of the pipeline.

Also, time is a "shell keyword", as shown by `type time`.

But nothing forbids the use of [compound commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) (and time each):

```
time comm1 | ( time comm2 )
```

So, you could workaround using a sub-shell, like this:

```
echo "12" | ( time python3 -c "a=input("");print(a)" )
```

Or also like this:

```
echo "12" | { time python3 -c "a=input("");print(a)"; }
```

Comment: Correct, time was introduced as a shell keyword by ksh88 and other shells copied this idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to time commands for performance reasons, I recommend not to use /usr/bin/time but either ptime(1) if this available on your platform - ptime gives a nanosecond resolution - or to use a recent Bourne Shell, as the Bourne Shell allows to automatically time all foreground commands (including shell builtins) with a microsecond resolution on all modern operating systems. To time all foreground commands in the Bourne Shell, call: `set -o time` and set TIMEFORMAT to a useful content to get a higher resolution, e.g.: `%6:E real %6U user %6S sys %P%% cpu %I+%Oio %Fpf+%Ww`

/usr/bin/time typically has a fixed resolution of 10ms or 1ms.